# How to check scope id after creating a new scope on Websphere portal?

Tags: search, scope, websphere-portal, ibm-wcm

I created a new scope named `ScopeBIDV` on *Websphere Portal 8.5* following this tutorial:
[IBM - Managing Search Scopes and Custom Links](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_8.0.0/admin/h_search_managesearch.html).

Now my panel looks like this:

[image]

How can I check the scope id?

Comment: I improved the question text and included the image and link.

Comment: did you try the url I gave it will show you the id of the search scope

Answer (score 0):

you can see the scope ids by going to this url
http://localhost:port/wps/mycontenthandler/searchfeed/scopes

Comment: tks #Crosstalk22 
I got it

Comment: Hello #Crosstalk22,today i want get all scopeId in websphere portal by this link : 

 but i get error message:
Error 400: EJCBD0021E: The URI [searchfeed:scopes] and parameters [['digest'=['QGlXZmhAzXTxj9OwYVbbTg']]] could not be processed: []
Are you understand this error ?
How can i fix it ?
Tks !

Comment: did you authenticate first, first login to portal, then go to that url

Comment: sure, i login then run that url. but still get error message .

Comment: are you going through the webserver, or directly to the server, i just tried on my no search set up machine and got redirect to http://hostname:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/!ut/p/digest!BPhg08Twr7RHC6hj_n6CYQ/searchfeed/scopes . and saw this result . <atom:feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<atom:title>Available Scopes</atom:title>
<atom:link href="searchfeed:scopes" rel="self" ....

Comment: also I just verified if you go to just /wps/contenthandler/searchfeed/scopes . it will show you public scopes as well you could go to https://support.hp.com/wps/contenthandler/searchfeed/scopes and see you should get a response